# Проверить на существование поля в ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc

Как проверить есть ли в ResultSet поле с заданным именем? То есть, перед тем, как сделать

```
resultSet.getInt("id")
```

нужно проверить есть ли данное поле в наборе.

Comment: Это происходит при вызове метода `getInt`.  В случает, если вы, делаете переопределение метода и не делаете проверки, у вас может возникнуть недоразумения. Хотелось бы видеть метод `getInt`. И в целом код и задачу, более подробно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно получить информацию обо всех колонках в данном `resultSet` а далее уже выполнить соответствующие проверки. Например, так:

```
private static boolean isExist(ResultSet resultSet, String columnName) throws SQLException {
    if (columnName == null || (columnName = columnName.trim()).isEmpty())
        return false;

    ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
    for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++)
        if (columnName.equals(metaData.getColumnName(i)))
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Вариант с ResultSetMetaData имеет место быть, но
for (int i = 1; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); i++) т.к. Columns нумеруются с 1.

Comment: Спасибо, хорошее замечание по поводу нумерации @HappyFamily

Answer (score 0):

Вам не нужно делать такую проверку, т.к. она бессмысленна! Метод `getInt()` бросит исключение `SQLException`, если такого столбца не будет найдено в результирующем наборе. Это даст понять, где произошла ошибка и исправить ее.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что нужно проверять наличие поля в результате не для поиска ошибок.

Comment: Sergey Klunichenko, могли бы Вы дать более подробный ответ? Чем Ваш ответ отличается от ответа Oleg Marchenko? Спасибо.